# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, android-animation

I am not using any animation in my project, when tested on emulator it works fine but when deployed to google playstore, it starts crashing with the above exception.

Comment: provide stack trace..

Comment: make sure to check your proguard/r8 configuraiton

Comment: Please how do I write a proguard rule for navigation component @hakim